# `make4ht`, `tex4ht`: when called from python, hits a write permission error if input file supplied with forward slashes

Tags: tex4ht, python, make4ht

I have a directory where I have the following `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=16pt, paper=letter]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{A test \LaTeX to HTML page}
\maketitle

\section{Section One}

Hello world. Here is some mathematics:
    \begin{equation}
        x + y = 3
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Then, I run a python script with the following commands:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["make4ht", "A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tex"])
```

When this command is called, the following error is reached:

```
) (a:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/tex4ht.sty
--- needs --- tex4ht A:/test_tex_sources/test_article ---

A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tmp: Forbidden to open for writing
! I can't write on file `A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tmp'.
l.966           \immediate\openout15=\jobname.tmp

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name:
```

On the other hand, if I provide the following python script:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["make4ht", "test_article.tex"])
```

everything works okay! In addition, if I run the following through command line, and not Python:

```
make4ht "A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tex"
```

then again, everything works okay.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `make4ht`, it constructs wrong `-jobname` for LaTeX when a full path to document is specified. The command call to LaTeX is following:

```
latex -jobname=$input "tex4ht.sty loading,\input $tex_file"
```

in your sample, it is

```
latex -jobname=A:/test_tex_sources/test_article "tex4ht.sty loading,\input A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tex"
```

correct call would be

```
latex -jobname=test_article "tex4ht.sty loading,\input A:/test_tex_sources/test_article.tex"
```

so `jobname` should be without directory path

I've fixed [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) sources, so you can use the development version until I post fix the update to CTAN